Is it possible to run a car without a carburetor?
Is it possible to run my car without a carburetor, or will doing so cause damage and prevent it from running?
Does it damage or wear anything? what actually happen to the car.

Most modern cars don’t have a carburettor.  Which car are you talking about?

If your car has a carburettor, how are you planning on fuelling the engine without the carburettor?

@HandyHowie, I'm talking about the 1st Generation Toyota Corolla

@HandyHowie I want  to replace it with the electronic fuel injection system(EFI). If it's possible.

Retrofit kits may be available from aftermarket suppliers. You would also need injectors, an engine management system, prossibly a different inlet manifold, and various sensors.


Is it possible to run my car without a carburetor?

Yes, you can theoretically run it without a carburetor. How would that happen? Well, if a carburetor was fitted to the engine in the first place, then you'd still need to be able to meter fuel into the engine. You could theoretically drain fuel directly into the intake manifold by hand, but there's some huge drawbacks to doing so. The carburetor performs several functions, one of them (as mentioned) is to meter fuel. That way you get (presumably) the correct amount of fuel per the amount of air which is incoming to the engine. The other thing it does is limits the amount of air incoming to the engine via the throttle plates. The more air, the faster it can run, and the higher the engine will rev. Without the throttle plates, the engine will run as fast as it can.
NOTE: Since you specified "carburetor", I'm assuming we are only talking about gasoline (petrol) based engines, and not diesel fueled engines, which run in a completely different manner.
Also, as Handy Howie pointed out in comments, you can run an engine without a carb by using a fuel injection system. Most modern vehicles today use such a system as it provides better runability, gas mileage, and tuning ability, with less harmful exhaust emissions ... plus many other benefits over a carburetor.

will doing so cause damage and prevent it from running?

If you don't get the fueling correct, the engine can still run, but it can cause a lean or rich state, which isn't good for the engine. Too lean and you'll start melting parts or it might not run. Too rich and you'll start gumming up the works by flooding your engine with excess fuel, which thins oil, washes down cylinder walls, and creates huge exhaust issues which will burn up your catalytic converter (which may get hot enough to burn up your vehicle). Too much fuel can also cause your engine not to run as well.

Thinning the oil does not provide protection to the metal parts which the oil keeps apart, thus can cause metal to metal contact which causes wear.
Washing down cylinders means you won't get the ring to cylinder wall sealing you'd normally expect, which would kill performance allowing combustion gasses to pass beyond them into the crankcase. With the cylinders washed down, you'd also get ring/piston metal to metal contact with the cylinder, which would cause major amounts of wear/damage to the engine.
When raw gas is dumped into the catalytic converter, the cat tries to keep up with the extra fuel by converting it from hydrocarbon to CO2 and water vapor. The byproduct of this is heat. There is a LOT of energy in gasoline. This process will continue to produce heat which will build up over time. This buildup can cause the cat to get so hot it will start heating things around it, which means it can cause things to catch fire. It is an ugly chain reaction, but have no doubt it can do it.

To go back to your original question, "Can you run your engine without a carburetor?" ... the answer is yes. Should you or would it make sense? Absolutely not, unless you're replacing it with a fuel injection system.
